# Icon on a JFreeChart XY Plot

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have an XY plot of positions and want the newest point to be an icon.  Is this possible in JFreeChart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On an xy plot you would need to keep track of the last xy point added and then add it using something like the following:

```
double x = 150;
double y = 300;
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("/path/to/your/icon.png");
XYAnnotation xyannotation = new XYImageAnnotation(x, y, imageIcon.getImage());
plot.addAnnotation(xyannotation);
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn off the annotation offset?

Comment: Sorry anwered my own question.