# Java charts - Need to build a chart on the fly using a custom image for the chart

Tags: java, charts

We would like to create a chart on the fly using a custom image that we design. This would be used in a Java 1.5 web app.  An example would be to show a chart representing a ratio of men to women. We would want the chart to be a linear row of women icons and men icons in which the number of women icons would be the percentage of women and the number of men icons would be the percentage of men. Is there anyway to achieve this.

Comment: I think, this question was asked several times at this forum ([Simplest Java chart library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384276), [Best java 3D pie chart API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403743)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) does what I think you're looking for.  To render a bar as a row of icons, you'll probably end up needing to play around with [`XYBarRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBarRenderer.html), perhaps with a custom implementation of [`XYBarPainter`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBarPainter.html).

You can also include icons on line charts, etc. as well; see [ShawnD's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528827/icon-on-a-jfreechart-xy-plot) from a couple years back.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) is a good option. Nice and easy to learn, with a lot of features. Take a look at their showcase.

Comment: I would need the web app to put the chart in a PDF using iText. It looks like google is geared for HTML and javascript. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with [jCharts](http://jcharts.sourceforge.net/) in the past.

The trouble with google charts, is that that is a third party service you don't control.  Also, if you want to write that chart into a pdf (or some printable format) at some point, then having it be delivered client side could be a problem.